# Autosuggestion in post creation

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, social-interfaces, android

I'm designing one specific medical application and got stucked with autosuggestions.

The idea is to write a post and include medical terms in it and do it without tag system. 
Should work like this: While typing device recognizes the terms and convert them into hyperlinks with explanations.

The main problem is to have an easier input for these terms and use autosuggestions. Terms are so specific that usual keyboard suggestions can't help with it. Maybe in the future we will work on AI, but now it's out of scope.
Another problem is cases and plural forms.

One of the solutions could be to use so-called Tap-Ahead interface, I added wireframes for that.

[image]

Another solution is to have a kind of switcher to the term-writing mode. But it's the same as to have a tag system and requires an additional tap. Also wireframes.

[image]
What do you think could be better for user? How can I improve the designs?

Comment: Would it be practical/effective to simply link the terms after they've been typed, or are you trying to assist with the typeahead functionality at the same time? To ask a different way: is the main feature here the typeahead, the link to an explanation, or both?

Comment: we already link the terms after typing. now like an improvement we'd like to assist users with typing. to answer a different way: both are important

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is how Facebook monitors free text input to suggest tagging friends.

> [image: Facebook tag demonstration]
>
> (Image taken from [an article on snaphow.com](http://www.snaphow.com/4895/tag-status-comments-in-facebook-with-shorter-firstname-or-lastname/))

This would also address your need to adjust capitalization, suffixes, etc. It also doesn't take the user out of the "typing" workflow, as they could easily just tap the suggestion and continue typing.